# How to listen for a page $emit in a nuxt layout?

Tags: vue.js, dom-events, nuxt.js

*Nuxt 2.15.6;* I want to switch the layout of my menu component by dynamically switching menu components in my root layout.

`default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <component :is="navLayout"></component>
  <Nuxt :navLayout="navLayout = $event" />
</template>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    navLayout: "default"
  };
},
```

In the "child" components of , my pages eg. *login.vue* *(/login)* I `$emit` an event;

```js
...
import nav2 from "@/layouts/nav2";
...
created() {
  this.$emit("navLayout", nav2);
},
```

Now it seems to be the `<Nuxt>` component is not able to catch the event. I also tried calling a `<Nuxt @navLayout="test()" />` method.

How can I avoid `this.$root.$emit(...);` in my `login.vue` and

```js
this.$root.$on("navLayout", navLayout => {
  this.navLayout = navLayout;
});
```

in `default.vue`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: This answer works fine as it looks like you cannot do it right now: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8122#issuecomment-709443008

In the child component

```html
<button @click="$nuxt.$emit('eventName', 'nice payload')">nice</button>
```

On the default layout

```html
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$nuxt.$on('eventName', ($event) => this.test($event))
  },
  methods: {
    test(e) {
      console.log('test ok >>', e)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Putting a listener on `Nuxt` itself does **not** work.

```html
<Nuxt @navLayout="navLayout = $event" :navLayout="navLayout" />
```

I can see the event go and the listener plugged to `<nuxt></nuxt>` but it does not trigger any method with the listener...

PS: works for `<nuxt-child></nuxt-child>` at least.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the same Gh post ;D and somehow it seems not to be possible with the <Nuxt> component. 
This would be the legit way to do it then but I also see that using layouts like Imre suggested is an approach. I will mark this as solved as your answer supports the inital question. Thank you!!

Comment: I guess that the team did not bother fixing this because of the way Nuxt3 may handle things in a different manner (maybe, I'm not part of the core team). Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but it seems to me that you are trying to do yourself what layouts are meant to do. This would mean that you would create a layout with the menu component for login, a default layout etc. like this:

login.vue

```
<template>
  <LoginMenu>
  <Nuxt/>
</template>
```

default.vue

```
<template>
  <DefaultMenu>
  <Nuxt/>
</template>
```

On your page you would do:

```
export default {
   layout: login
}
```

And then that would load the layout with the login menu component. On all other pages it would load the default menu.

More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/layouts/

Comment: I am aware of layouts. But this would limit me to the use of different layouts for switching the menu. What if I want to switch the main content in <Nuxt> to a different layout later. 
I would also have to change all menu layouts - for example if I add a changing footer. With a nested layout the nested layout would not be changable by using the "layout" annotation in the components.
Am I getting this right?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer to your problem. Just to respond. It is difficult for me to see what you are trying to accomplish, but in general I would separate the application in pages. Both pages and layouts can import components. Whatever needs to be on multiple pages becomes a layout and the rest is a page. Looking at it this way the framework works for most cases. Trying to do it differently is always possible, but I think the key is to let the framework work for you, not work against it. Again, I don't understand your situation fully, so apologies if I'm off base.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I choose your way and created multiple layouts for the different menus. Thanks you your advice!
 I I marked the other answer as the answer because it fits the needs for the initial question