# How to change data in default layout from nested components in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have layout `default.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <div class="body-wrapper">
      <Nuxt :numberThird="numberThird" />
    </div>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      numberThird: 3
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Here I am trying to pass prop `numberThird`.

I want to be able to change this value in the future through components that are deeply nested.

But there is a problem: my pages don't accept this prop (`numberThird`), they treat it as `$parent.$attr`.

**The question is:** can I somehow change this value through deeply nested child components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817642/8816585
Props and listeners are not the most friendly on either `<nuxt>` nor `<nuxt-link>`.

Kinda confirmed here by Alexander too: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8669#issuecomment-764006062

You better off using Vuex in this case, especially if you are aiming to something deep. Props drilling is not recommended most of the time.