# Is it possible to listen to NuxtChild event

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a simple setup using a NuxtChild component for a nested route:

I have the following file tree:

```
-| pages/
---| parent/
------| child.vue
------| child2.vue
------| child3.vue
---| parent.vue
```

And I want to listen to event from child in the parent component.
I tried the way it's supposed to work:

```html
<NuxtChild @error="showErrorDialog"/>
```

and in my component:

```js
this.$emit('error');
```

But it doesn't work, the `showErrorDialog` is not triggered in the parent component.
Is something wrong or is it just impossible?

Comment: Not really, it still doesn't work for me, using nuxt-child or NuxtChild

Comment: What is not working? Can you be more explicit? Do you see the emit in your vue devtools?

Comment: The event seems to be fired according to the vue devtools but the NuxtChild doesn't catch it

Comment: I've updated my answer. This should work, pay attention to your structure and to any typos.

Comment: Otherwise, you can totally use the `$nuxt.$emit` solution even for a `<nuxt-child>` tag, works too!

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with `<nuxt-child>` and it should work as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817642/8816585

Do you see something in your Vue devtools events tab?

---

Not sure what I can say, it totally works on my side.
Maybe make a repro and let's see what is the issue.

`PageCareConfiguration` component (aka children)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$emit('test', 'pizza')">
      test
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

`PageCare` component (aka parent)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-child @test="printConsoleLog"></nuxt-child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    printConsoleLog(name) {
      console.log("printConsoleLog'ed >>", name)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]